# How to properly fetch data from tab separated fields in text file

Tags: c, file-io, io

I am trying to learn how to import data from tab separated fields in a text file. Here it is an example of what I am trying to fetch from an external file called `users.in`:

```
1   joshmith    mypwd   John    Smith   Awesome Road 103
2   jane_doe    strongpwd   Jane    Doe Lucky Street 201
3   august84    goodpwd August May  Red Boulevard 24
```

here it is the structure that is supposed to keep the data...

```
typedef struct User
{
    int id;
    char username[20];
    char password[40];
    char firstname[20];
    char lastname[20];
    char address[120];
} User;
```

... and of course the code that should handle the operation:

```
User *u = (User *)malloc(sizeof(User)*4);
int i = 0;

    while (6 == fscanf(data_file, "%d\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\n", &(u+i)->id, (u+i)->username, (u+i)->password, (u+i)->firstname, (u+i)->lastname, (u+i)->address))
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "%d %s %s %s %s %s\n", (u+i)->id, (u+i)->username, (u+i)->password, (u+i)->firstname, (u+i)->lastname, (u+i)->address);
        i++;
    }
```

the loop manages to go through the first iteration... and then it stops. Here it is the output:

```
1 joshmith mypwd John Smith Awesome Road 103
2
```

can anyone help me figure out why is this happening? What is the proper way to import such formatted data?

Comment: @user3121023 yes!! thank you! why the extra space at the beginning of the formatting string? What's that for?

Comment: Shouldn't `%d` itself already discard preceding whitespaces itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your format string is that the last scanset you're using is `%[^\t]` while most likely ends with a `\n`, although of course it could possibly be that it ends with a `\t`. If it is certain that it ends with a `\n`, then simply changing that last one should suffice:

```
"%d\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\n]\n"
                         // changed this ^ from t to n
```

If it may also be a `\t`, then you may use the following:

```
"%d\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\n\t]%*[\n\t]"
// %[^\n\t] discards and assigns whatever found until a '\t' or '\n' is encountered
// %*[\n\t] discards and only discards '\n's and '\t's
// ... until something else is encountered
```

As an additional information, a space `' '` inside a format string matches to zero or more of any whitespace character and discards them. It essentially is like `%*[ \t\n]` telling the `-scanf` to: *match any (if any) `' '`, `'\t'` and `'\n'` until you encounter something else and discard them.*

Answer (score 1):

I would use [fgets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c37dh6kf.aspx) to read each line into a string and then use [strtok](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8d19sb.aspx) with `\t` as a delimiter character to extract the tokens; the first token in each line can be converted to a number using [atoi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd5xkb5c.aspx).

NOTE: using `atoi()` means that an invalid number will be returned as a zaero value, so you cannot distinguish between these without extra logic